# Mapbox - Ignoring icon padding when calling queryRenderedFeatures

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using Mapbox's `queryRenderedFeatures()` to handle hovering and clicking.

The issue is that some symbol layers have a fair amount of padding to reduce the density of symbols, and this padding is taken in consideration for the symbol's hitboxes. As a result, a naive implementation will think that the mouse is hovering or has clicked a symbol while it is not the case visually.

Here's an example of the kind of hitbox present in the style (the red ones are from a hidden symbol):

[image: hitbox]

With no filtering on `queryRenderedFeatures()` results, the mouse will be considered as hovering the point as soon as it enters the hitbox.

I tried filtering out padded features manually by computing the point-to-cursor distance in pixels. It works ok for round or square symbols that are centered on their point, but gives incorrect results for rectangular symbols or those that have a translated position.

I also tried to find a way to get the symbol's position and size in pixels so that I can recheck the collision without padding but couldn't find any method for that.

Is there any way to use `queryRenderedFeatures()` or an equivalent while ignoring icon padding? Or any alternative to produce the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried to find a way to get the symbol's position and size in pixels so that I can recheck the collision without padding but couldn't find any method for that.

You can get the anchor position for a symbol, in pixels, by:

1. Using `querySourceFeatures()` or `queryRenderedFeatures()` to obtain the feature.
2. Using `map.project()` to convert the feature's `lngLat` into pixel coordinates.

If your symbol is not placed at the anchor, you will have to perform the same calculation manually.

I don't think you can do much better than this method overall:

1. Detect a hit within the padded bounding box, find the feature's geometry
2. Get the pixel coordinates of the feature's anchor
3. Offset those coordinates using what you know about the symbol's offset etc.
4. Calculate the distance from there to the mouse cursor.

Comment: Unless I missed something, don't I still need to know the symbol's dimensions in pixels even if the symbol is centered on its anchor? Having the anchor's location in pixel coordinates is actually already what I do today to re-filter the coordinates but this filtering is based on a semi-arbitrary pixel distance which does not work for every symbol type.

Comment: I'm assuming that you know the dimensions of your own assets.

Comment: We have several clickable symbol layers with different symbols and regularly make changes to the Mapbox style. Having to list every symbol dimensions and know when they're being used would be cumbersome to maintain, so we'd like to have a generic method to handle this.